# ROS transform Turtlebot Kinect coordinates to gmapping world coordinates

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, coordinates, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We are using gmapping to build our world. And we get the (x, y, z) coordinates from Kinect (PointCloud) by subscribing to the topic /camera/depth_registered/points.

We get the position of our Turtlebot by subscribing to the topic /move_base/feedback. The question is, if we get the Kinect (PointCloud) coordinates from a certain object, how do we tell the robot to go there? We know that you need to send a message to the topic /move_base_simple/goal, but how do we transform the coordinates from Kinect into "world coordinates" (the world that was build by using gmapping).

There is a similar problem in this topic - http://answers.ros.org/question/9506/how-to-transform-a-point-cloud-from-camera but I don't know what is the destination frame and how to use it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34234/ros-transform-turtlebot-kinect-coordinates-to-gmapping-world-coordinates/) by [ZeroCool](https://answers.ros.org/users/2321/zerocool/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you read through the tf documentation ( http://ros.org/wiki/tf ), specifically the tutorials ( http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials )?

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1